# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, src

I keep on getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of null" whenever my code hits the js code below to open a popup when clicked on a label on aspx page. Please help.

```
function openWindow(which) {
            //alert(which);
            //alert(document.getElementById('iframeClass').src);
            document.getElementById('iframeClass').src = 'ViewIovationResults.aspx?ordernumber=' + which;

            //alert(document.getElementById('iframeClass').src);
                if (divMap.style["display"] == "none") {
                divMap.style["display"] = "";

            }
        }

    <tr>
        <td width="190"><STRONG>Order Number :</STRONG></td>                                                                    <td width="200">                                                                <a  onclick="javascript:openWindow('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Order Number") %>')"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Order Number") %></a>                                                          </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: for starters what is `divMap` ? were is it defined?

Comment: divMap is the id of the div inside which I have the table that holds the "order Nmmber" label.

Comment: the you should have inside the function `var divMap = document.getElementById('divMap ');` before calling it. Unless its defined already outside the function and within scope.

Comment: Ok, nice! I posted it as an answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have inside the function `var divMap = document.getElementById('divMap ');` before calling it. Unless its defined already outside the function and within scope.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information is hard to say, but if that's the problematic code then, by the time that script is executed, there is no element with id `iframeClass` or/and `divMap` is null.

So In short:

- Do you have an html element with id `iframeClass`?
- Do you have an html element with id `divMap`?
- If both elements exist on the page, are you executing that script **after** they are loaded?

Comment: <div class="showDiv" id="divMap" style="DISPLAY: none" onclick="javascript:closeWindow();"
    align="center" runat="server" name="divConfirm">
    <iframe id="iframeClass" name="iframeClass" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" src="ViewIovationReesults.aspx"
     frameBorder="0" width="300"  height="200"></iframe>
    
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not have an element on your page with an ID value of `iframeClass`. Verify the name of this element or there is no variable named `divMap`.